# How to automate docker deployment based on GitHub webhook?

Tags: node.js, linux, git, docker, continuous-integration

So I have inherited an application, and am not too happy with the current deployment workflow. There is a docker instance running on an ec2 server, and developers have been merging their local work like this:

```
rsync -arhvz --progress ./ ubuntu@52.12.345.67:/home/ubuntu/app --exclude node_modules
```

And then going into the server itself and running a `deploy.sh` script. I would simply like a `push` event to the master branch to trigger this sync and deploy. How is it possible? As far as I know we don't pay for a Docker hub account - we don’t have private docker registry.

Comment: Without know what `deploy.sh` it is difficult to recommend next steps. Maybe you can add more of the steps in the current process and the `deploy.sh` script to the question? If you are building an image somewhere in this pipeline it would probably also be helpful to see the `Dockerfile` and any other parts of the code that might be relevant to deploying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some solutions :

- use a git [pre-push hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) script which will execute the script before each local push to remote
- create a bare git repo on your server, push your change to this git remote and checkout the last change using [post-receive hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)
- track push events on Github with Github webhook, you will need to have your server listen to a port in order to receive the webhook events

## pre-push hook

In your local repository, edit/create `.git/hooks/pre-push` file :

```sh
#!/bin/bash
rsync -arhvz --progress ./ ubuntu@52.12.345.67:/home/ubuntu/app --exclude node_modules
ssh ubuntu@52.12.345.67 "/home/ubuntu/deploy.sh"
```

This way, your modification will sync before each local push to remote. The `deploy.sh` is also triggered

## setup a git repo on your server and deploy to it using git

You can create a bare git repo on your server and create a `post-receive` hook script that will use `git` to checkout your server repo. From [this guide](https://gist.github.com/noelboss/3fe13927025b89757f8fb12e9066f2fa) :

```sh
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    # only checking out the master (or whatever branch you would like to deploy)
    if [[ $ref =~ .*/master$ ]];
    then
        echo "Master ref received.  Deploying master branch to production..."
        git --work-tree=/home/ubuntu/app/deploy-folder/ --git-dir=/home/ubuntu/app/project.git/ checkout -f
    else
        echo "Ref $ref successfully received.  Doing nothing: only the master branch may be deployed on this server."
    fi
done
```

Note that this solution only uses git

## Github Webhook

You can use this [docker-hook](https://github.com/schickling/docker-hook) project which is a Python server listening for a `POST` on your webhook uri. It was originally used for Docker Hub webhook but also works for Github webhook (though not parsing the events).

#### Webhook

On your server :

- download docker-hook python script

```sh
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/schickling/docker-hook/master/docker-hook > /usr/local/bin/docker-hook; chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-hook
```

- start it with a token (generated with `uuidgen` for example) :

```sh
docker-hook -t 3ea4e9d8-8fff-47e5-a704-65ab21de6963 -c /path/to/deploy.sh
```

In Github, go to your repo settings, create the webhook with the token as path :

[image]

Check that the webhook is working (in Recent Deliveries tab)

#### Deploy key

Now, as you want to trigger a `git pull` on your server, you will need to generate a [Deploy Key](https://github.com/blog/2024-read-only-deploy-keys) which is a ssh key used to deploy (read-only), you will need, on server side :

- install `git` if not already installed
- generate a key
- copy this key in your repo/settings/Deploy key tab

See [this post](https://gist.github.com/zhujunsan/a0becf82ade50ed06115) for a complete tutorial

[image]

Now you need to edit your `deploy.sh` script to perform a `git pull` or a fresh `git clone` to the location of your choice